# How can I test jquery call using jasmine?

Tags: jquery, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the next method in angular's component:

```
private onTopClick() {
  $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
}
```

How I can test this with jasmine? Just to check that 'animate' method has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a couple of functions ...

- First, set up spy for `animate` function. Probably you would want to do this for all your tests or before each, well may be just for one test; You may also want to do after the spy intercept the call, for example `.and.callFake()` or `.and.callThrough()`, etc...

  ```
  beforeEach(function() {
       spyOn($.fn, "animate");
  });
  ```
- After inside your actual test(s) check if `animate` function was called. May looks like ...

  ```
   it("should call '$(selector).animate'", function () {
        onTopClick();
        expect($.fn.animate).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
  ```

More on Jasmine Testing is [over here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html).

Comment: thanks for the response. But unfortunetly, it doesn't work:
[errors](http://prntscr.com/fdzsu5) + I have the next error in Visual Studio Code: "Property 'animate' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'."

Comment: @Maxim Sorry for confusion, I fixed the code example.